# Row too wide in Table!

Tags: tables

I have the table below. But row 11 and 20 are too wide so I would like to have them split in two in a way that it still looks nice. So that the end result looks something like

```
11  Crude petroleum and natural gas; services incidental
    to oil and gas extraction excluding surveying



\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Industries}
\label{industries}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1  & Products of agriculture, hunting, and related services                                             \\
2  & Products of forestry, logging, and related services                                                \\
5  & Fish and other fishing products; services incidental of fishing                                    \\
10 & Coal and lignite;
peat                                                                             \\
11 & Crude petroleum and natural gas; services incidental to oil and gas extraction excluding surveying \\
12 & Uranium and thorium ores                                                                           \\
13 & Metal ores                                                                                         \\
14 & Other mining and quarrying products                                                                \\
15 & Food products and beverages                                                                        \\
16 & Tobacco products                                                                                   \\
17 & Textiles                                                                                           \\
18 & Wearing apparel; furs                                                                              \\
19 & Leather and leather products                                                                       \\
20 & Wood and products of wood and cork (except furniture); articles of straw and plaiting materials    \\
21 & Pulp, paper, and paper products                                                                    \\
22 & Printed matter and recorded media                                                                  \\
23 & Coke, refined petroleum products, and nuclear fuels                                                \\
24 & Chemicals, chemical products, and man-made fibers                                                  \\
25 & Rubber and plastic products                                                                        \\
26 & Other non-metallic mineral products                                                                \\
27 & Basic metals                                                                                       \\
28 & Fabricated metal products, except machinery and equipment                                          \\
29 & Machinery and equipment n.e.c.                                                                     \\
30 & Office machinery and computers                                                                     \\
31 & Electrical machinery and apparatus n.e.c.                                                         \\
32    & Radio, television, and communication equipment and apparatus \\
33    & Medical, precision and optical instruments, watches, and clocks \\
34    & Motor vehicles, trailers, and semi-trailers \\
35    & Other transport equipment \\
36    & Furniture; other manufactured goods n.e.c.\\
37    & Secondary raw materials

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: that's what "p" columns do.  Something like `\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}`... See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for a `tabularx`, I guess:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo, get rid of it.

\begin{document}
11 Crude petroleum and natural gas; services incidental
to oil and gas extraction excluding surveying

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Industries}
    \label{industries}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX} % or even \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}rX@{}} if you want to save horizontal space.
        1  & Products of agriculture, hunting, and related services                                             \\
        2  & Products of forestry, logging, and related services                                                \\
        5  & Fish and other fishing products; services incidental of fishing                                    \\
        10 & Coal and lignite; peat                                                                             \\
        11 & Crude petroleum and natural gas; services incidental to oil and gas extraction excluding surveying \\
        12 & Uranium and thorium ores                                                                           \\
        13 & Metal ores                                                                                         \\
        14 & Other mining and quarrying products                                                                \\
        15 & Food products and beverages                                                                        \\
        16 & Tobacco products                                                                                   \\
        17 & Textiles                                                                                           \\
        18 & Wearing apparel; furs                                                                              \\
        19 & Leather and leather products                                                                       \\
        20 & Wood and products of wood and cork (except furniture); articles of straw and plaiting materials    \\
        21 & Pulp, paper, and paper products                                                                    \\
        22 & Printed matter and recorded media                                                                  \\
        23 & Coke, refined petroleum products, and nuclear fuels                                                \\
        24 & Chemicals, chemical products, and man-made fibers                                                  \\
        25 & Rubber and plastic products                                                                        \\
        26 & Other non-metallic mineral products                                                                \\
        27 & Basic metals                                                                                       \\
        28 & Fabricated metal products, except machinery and equipment                                          \\
        29 & Machinery and equipment n.e.c.                                                                     \\
        30 & Office machinery and computers                                                                     \\
        31 & Electrical machinery and apparatus n.e.c.                                                          \\
        32 & Radio, television, and communication equipment and apparatus                                       \\
        33 & Medical, precision and optical instruments, watches, and clocks                                    \\
        34 & Motor vehicles, trailers, and semi-trailers                                                        \\
        35 & Other transport equipment                                                                          \\
        36 & Furniture; other manufactured goods n.e.c.                                                         \\
        37 & Secondary raw materials        
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach, using `enumerate` This is mainly because your table only consisted of two columns, where the first was just an increasing number, with two exceptions, the number `5` and `10`.

This reduces the amount of manual writing a lot and gives more flexibility, as you don't need to write all numbers manually, you simply change those that you want to set manually, and let the counter take care of the rest.

Of course, you could create your own counter for use in a `tabular` as well. But using `enumerate` does have some advantages.

Here, I've added two options, as can be seen in the output. One using `multicol` to distribute the list in two columns, and one without. In the code, simply uncomment the commented lines to switch between them.

**Output**

[image: With and without multicols]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}
  \item Products of agriculture, hunting, and related services                                             
  \item Products of forestry, logging, and related services\setcounter{enumi}{4}                                                
  \item Fish and other fishing products; services incidental of fishing\setcounter{enumi}{9}                                    
  \item Coal and lignite; peat                                                                             
  \item Crude petroleum and natural gas; services incidental to oil and gas extraction excluding surveying 
  \item Uranium and thorium ores                                                                           
  \item Metal ores                                                                                         
  \item Other mining and quarrying products                                                                
  \item Food products and beverages                                                                        
  \item Tobacco products                                                                                   
  \item Textiles                                                                                           
  \item Wearing apparel; furs                                                                              
  \item Leather and leather products                                                                       
  \item Wood and products of wood and cork (except furniture); articles of straw and plaiting materials    
  \item Pulp, paper, and paper products                                                                    
  \item Printed matter and recorded media                                                                  
  \item Coke, refined petroleum products, and nuclear fuels                                                
  \item Chemicals, chemical products, and man-made fibers                                                  
  \item Rubber and plastic products                                                                        
  \item Other non-metallic mineral products                                                                
  \item Basic metals                                                                                       
  \item Fabricated metal products, except machinery and equipment                                          
  \item Machinery and equipment n.e.c.                                                                     
  \item Office machinery and computers                                                                     
  \item Electrical machinery and apparatus n.e.c.                                                         
  \item Radio, television, and communication equipment and apparatus 
  \item Medical, precision and optical instruments, watches, and clocks 
  \item Motor vehicles, trailers, and semi-trailers 
  \item Other transport equipment 
  \item Furniture; other manufactured goods n.e.c.
  \item Secondary raw materials
\end{enumerate}
%\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```